# Retrieving data from a database in another thread(Unity3D)

Tags: c#, multithreading, unity-game-engine

I currently have a code which retrieves data from a database and visualizes it in unity3D. However, everytime it retrieves data in the FixedUpdate() function, it spikes dramatically every 1 second. I'm thinking about using threading to do this but i'm not sure what i'm doing wrong.

This is the Function i call in the thread.

```
 public void retrievefromDB(){
                            if (timeStep - prevTimeStep > 99) {
                                    timeStep -= 1; //special for this dataset
   query = "SELECT * FROM GridData2 WHERE timestep=" + timeStep;

                                    if (showParent)
                                            query += " AND (Level != 10)";
                                    else
                                            query += " AND (Level == 10)";

      query += " AND temperature >= " + minTemp + " AND temperature <= " + maxTemp;
                                    dt.Rows.Clear ();
                                    dt = sqlDB.ExecuteQuery (query);

                                    prevTimeStep = timeStep;
                            }

            }
```

This code lags the scene every 1 second therefore i tried to put it into a thread.

```
void FixedUpdate()
    {
    Thread testthread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(retrievefromDB));
        testthread.Start ();
}
```

After putting it in a thread, it keeps crashing the scene after awhile.
Can anyone tell me what I did wrongly? And how do i solve it?

Comment: In general, you *must not* access shared resources without some kind of synchronization. Even assuming `sqlDB` is thread-safe (which is not necessarily the case), `dt.Rows.Clear()` and `dt = ...` are *definitely* not thread-safe. It's just a disaster waiting to happen. If you want to stick to this kind of code (not a good idea), you'll at least need to `lock` around all access to `dt`. Of course, in your code as is this will eliminate the parallelism again, but just make sure to only change `dt` in the `lock` - load the data *before* taking the lock. The same applies to `timeStep` etc.

Comment: _"After putting it in a thread, it keeps crashing the scene after awhile"_ - A new thread will be created for each `FixedUpdate()` hence the crash.

Comment: Luaan Can you give me example of "locking" the code? I have no idea what you're talking about but it seems important

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It finally works now. Just had to add these in retrievefromDB()

```
public void retrievefromDB(){
      while(true){
                            if (timeStep - prevTimeStep > 99) {
                                    timeStep -= 1; //special for this dataset
   query = "SELECT * FROM GridData2 WHERE timestep=" + timeStep;

                                    if (showParent)
                                            query += " AND (Level != 10)";
                                    else
                                            query += " AND (Level == 10)";

      query += " AND temperature >= " + minTemp + " AND temperature <= " + maxTemp;
                                    dt.Rows.Clear ();
                                    dt = sqlDB.ExecuteQuery (query);

                                    prevTimeStep = timeStep;
                            }
           Thread.Sleep(1);
               }
            }
```

And put this into the Start() function

```
testThread = UnityThreadHelper.CreateThread (() =>
                                                     {
            UnityThreadHelper.TaskDistributor.Dispatch (() => retrievefromDB ());

        });

        testThread.Start ();
```

I'm using the threadhelper from
http://forum.unity3d.com/threads/unity-threading-helper.90128/ 
so u can go and check it out.
Thanks to everyone who helped! :)

Answer (score 4):

The cause of your original issue is relatively obvious: database access is slow. If you put a database call inline in the `FixedUpdate` method, you're going to essentially pause your game's movement while the DB access happens (which may well take a second if you have to initialise a connection, for example).

The main issue with your threaded code as posted is that you are starting a new thread *every time `FixedUpdate` is called*. That means you're starting 60 new threads per second (by default) which will very quickly cripple your game!

While it's fine to use C# threads in Unity for this sort of work, a better approach would be to create a *single* thread and allow that to manage the timing, rather than creating a new thread each time the job runs. That would mean creating the thread in `Awake()` or `Start()` instead, and then using `Thread.Sleep` or similar to handle the timing.

Coroutines (as suggested by Mihai in his answer) are great for fixing the timing of events, but they still run on the game thread: if you put your DB code in a coroutine, you'll still see pauses when it runs. If you must run this DB access every second, you need it in a proper thread.

That said, have you considered that the DB access might be unnecessary? A more performant model might be to cache all of the data up front and use it from memory when you need it. (This might not be possible if the data is very dynamic, or if you're running in a memory-restricted environment like a mobile device...)

Comment: The thing is if i call the Thread in Start function it won't update and will just run once. is there a way to keep reusing a thread rather than to keep creating a new one?

Comment: Put a loop in your thread's method, so that it'll run indefinitely (with the required delay). You'll also likely want a flag that you can use to signal the thread to terminate cleanly on request.

Comment: by Loop u mean something like  While(true){//Do something} right? Then how do i add the delay?

Comment: Yes, I mean that - or, more likely, `while (!_threadShouldEnd)` so that you can control the termination from outside the thread. If you're running that in a dedicated thread, there's no problem using `Thread.Sleep` to add the delay.

Answer (score 1):

Whatever you do, you need to stop accessing your database every frame.

You only need the result only once every 60 or frames. You can do this easily by using a variable in which you add up the time passed since last call.

As for multi-threading in Unity, you have three options:

- **A multi-threading framework** for Unity, like
  https://www.assetstore.unity3d.com/en/#!/content/7285
- **C# built-in threading**
  You need to be careful not to call Unity specific API from the secondary threads you spawn. It's OK to send over data structures like Vector3, Color, etc., but don't call reference objects like  GameObjects or Components.
  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd321439%28v=vs.110%29.aspx
- Unity **Coroutines**
  Coroutines are Unity's way of simulating multiple threads. It's quite a powerful tool for getting things to run asynchronously in the same thread
  http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/Coroutines.html

```
using System.Threading.Tasks;  

public class Example
{
    void StartOnDifferentThread()
    {
        Task.Factory
            .StartNew(() =>
            {
                FunctionToRun();
            })
            .ContinueWith(task =>
            {
                if (task.IsCompleted)
                {
                    // handle result
                }
                else if (task.IsFaulted)
                {
                    // handle error
                }
            });
    }

    void FunctionToRun()
    {
        // do stuff
    }
}
```

Comment: Oooo Another question. What do i need to change if i want the function to keep updating every second

Comment: You can just call it every second. `Task.Factory` uses a Pool of threads so it's not as expensive as it might seem. However, for this purpose, coroutines are a better fit. http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/Coroutines.html

Comment: You also need to stop calling this every frame. You only need the result only once every 60 or frames. You can do this easily by using a variable in which you add up the time passed since last call.